# To find only Latest Login Place of Subscribers Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

![enter image description here][1]I am using Neo4j Version 1.9.4. I want to find the latest Login Places of Each Subscribers.

The following Cypher Returns all Hits By The Subscriber. How can i get the Latest Hit alone for each Subscriber

```
START root=node(1) MATCH root
-[:TABLE]->hitParent
-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit
<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
RETURN DISTINCT hit.latitude, subscriber.Name
ORDER BY hit.id
```

Is it possible to get in those data in a Cypher Query?

The Data Model as follows,

```
node(1) - TABLE -> subscriberHits
node(1) - TABLE -> subscriber
subscriber - HAS_SUBSCRIBER -> sub1{Name:test1}
subscriber - HAS_SUBSCRIBER -> sub2{Name:test2}
subscriber - HAS_SUBSCRIBER -> sub3{Name:test3}
subscriberHits - SUBSCRIBER_HITS -> hit1{lat:5.55, lon:-20.89, id : 1}
subscriberHits - SUBSCRIBER_HITS -> hit2{lat:13:80, lon:80.89, id : 2}
subscriberHits - SUBSCRIBER_HITS -> hit3{lat:5:95, lon:-19.89, id : 3}
sub1 - HAS_HIT - hit1
sub1 - HAS_HIT - hit2
sub2 - HAS_HIT - hit3
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain your datamodel a bit?

Comment: @MichaelHunger : I have Modified My question with data Models.

Comment: @MichaelHunger : Please see the Console [link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/rnbhr0) . I am getting the First hit from the query but i need the Latest hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WITH clause to pipe the MATCH, collect the hit related nodes for each user, order this collection by hit.id and return the first one of the collection :

For your example this should be something like this :

```
START root=node(1) MATCH root
-[:TABLE]->hitParent
-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit
<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
WITH subscriber, hit, collect(hit) as hitsCollection
ORDER BY hit.id DESC
WITH subscriber, head(hitsCollection) as latestHit
RETURN subscriber.Name, latestHit.latitude
```

Comment: As the head will only fetch the first element, I think the DISTINCT is no more necessary for your use case, so I edited .

Comment: Willemsem : 
The above Query was not working for me. It is throwing error  **Expected `latestHit` to be a Map But it was a Scalar **. 
The Modified Query as follows, 
`START root=node(1) MATCH root
-[:TABLE]->hitParnt
-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit
<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
WITH subscriber, collect(hit) as hitsCollection
WITH subscriber, head(hitsCollection) as latestHit
RETURN subscriber.id, latestHit`

Comment: @SCKannan and what was inside the quotes after expected?

Comment: No.. it worked after i remove ORDER By from your query.. No i cant able to get the latitude from the Collection. The error was `Expected latestHit to be a Map But it was a Scalar `

Comment: mmmh can you provide a bit of data in neo4j console website or a simple csv that i can load

Comment: Here is the Console URL [link](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=cs5tuc) . it is returning the first One as the ORDER By is throwing the error

Comment: Willemsen : Here is the console with [link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/rnbhr0). The Modified Query as follows, `START root=node(0)
MATCH root-[:TABLE]->hitParnt-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
WITH subscriber, collect(hit) AS hitsCollection
WITH subscriber, head(hitsCollection) AS latestHit
RETURN latestHit.id AS hID, latestHit.lat AS lat,latestHit.lon AS lon, subscriber.id AS sid` . 
But the above query returns the first hit not the latest hit. I cant able to use the ORDER BY in above query..

Comment: Indeed I forgot to add "hit" to the WITH clause, this query is working :  START root=node(9)MATCH root -[:TABLE]->hitParnt-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriberWITH subscriber, collect(hit) AS hitsCollectionWITH subscriber, head(hitsCollection) AS latestHitRETURN subscriber.id, latestHit.latitude

Console link : http://console.neo4j.org/r/kiyp6g

Comment: Willemsen : I have added the hit as you suggested which returns all nodes. The Query as follows, `START root=node(0)
MATCH root -[:TABLE]->hitParnt-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
WITH subscriber, collect(hit) AS hitsCollection, hit
ORDER BY hit.id DESC 
WITH subscriber, head(hitsCollection) AS latestHit
RETURN subscriber.id, latestHit.lat, latestHit.id AS hID`

Answer (score 0):

The following Query works for Me,

```
START root=node(0)
MATCH root -[:TABLE]->hitParnt-[:SUBSCRIBER_HITS]->hit<-[:HAS_HIT]-subscriber
WITH hit AS hits, subscriber
ORDER BY hits.id DESC 
WITH subscriber, COLLECT(hits) AS hitsCollection
WITH subscriber, HEAD(hitsCollection) AS latestHit
RETURN subscriber.id AS subscriberId, latestHit.lat AS latitude, 
latestHit.id AS hID
```

The first WITH is to pipe the MATCH 
Then ORDER BY it by Latest One 
Then COLLECT it, 
Then use the HEAD to get the latest Hit.

Thanks for @Christophe Willemsen. Your answer helped me to find this solution...